# Double conversion UPS off a modified sine input?

Tags: inverter, wave, ups, sine

I have a 2000W modified sine wave inverter running from 12V bank in a tractor-trailer. It’s company owned, so no changing or adding equipment. Only viable solution I can see to achieve a sine wave is an online double conversion UPS.

Question is though will it run and not meet an untimely demise? I’ve tried running a gaming console on it and the fans rattled loudly in an alarming way. I know that cheaper UPS systems will induce a fault at the power. But, given this would be converting power constantly anyway, would it signal power loss all the time?

And again, would it cause damage to it? The cheapest one I can find is still an ungodly $600. Such a hassle this problem has been.

Only other solution I see is to invest in a battery station/solar generator. But 1500Wh is even more expensive and realistically would run the device for a few hours before taking half the day to recharge via dc adapter.

I don’t see the issue running directly off the inverter, but for some reason an Xbox Series S did not like it at all and I don’t want to plug something more expensive in that could be damaged. I can’t speculate much as to why it did. Maybe the fans were wired directly to AC? I don’t see that being logical. It’s a quality inverter. Tundra brand designed for trucks. About $500, but mostly is not sold publicly.

UPS manufacturer support is not very helpful and/or not reachable.

Headaches induced over this problem. Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on _”did not like it at all”_.

Comment: I think you'll find that this is the wrong site for asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the AC mains? If you got a double conversion UPS then it kind of suggests you have the mains, in which case why are you powering your console through the inverter? Using an inverter alone suggests that you're running the whole thing from DC batteries that get charged somewhere else?

Cheap inverters have really poor sine waves, they usually use width modulated square waves, and some are much finer or coarser than others. I'd honestly suggest measuring the output voltage and scoping it if you can, but I appreciate that might not be possible.

You may just have to buy a better (more expensive) inverter.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, "modified sine wave" inverters are no good for running sensitive electronics.  They can damage the power supplies of those electronic devices very quickly.

Consider buying a true sine wave inverter and connecting it directly to the truck battery, ignoring the fitted inverter.

If the UPS decides that the supply from the truck's inverter is no good, it will switch off its input and run only from its internal battery, until the battery runs flat.  That won't achieve anything.